# All ComboBoxes in a ListBox change when any 1 of them is changed

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, listbox

I have a `ListBox` on a form that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of a custom type.  Within each item there is a `ComboBox` bound to an enumeration type.  When the window loads, all `ComboBox`es are defaulted to a certain value.  When I change the `SelectedItem` for any one (from the UI, not from code), all other `ComboBox`es change to the same `SelectedItem`.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, here is my current XAML that is handling this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SyncOperationValues"
                        MethodName="GetNames"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:SyncOperationEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
...
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SyncListTemplate">
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,20,0" x:Name="olDetails"
            DataContext="{Binding Path=OlContact}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
            <ComboBox x:Name="SyncOp" 
                Width="120" Height="19"
                Margin="4,0,10,0" 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SyncOperationValues}}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding Operation}"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" />

...
```

and the `ListBox`:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="SyncList"
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StretchedContainerStyle}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SyncListTemplate}">
 ListBox>
```

I have tried some different options, like binding to a `CollectionView`; however nothing seems to work.  Can anyone point me to my mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found a solution.  I ended up writing a ValueConverter for the enumeration type.  I'd been under the impression that this was not necessary, but for some reason it is, at least if the ComboBox is within another list (ListBox in my case) of some sort.

I did need to set the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property to false as John M suggested, so thanks to John for that!  Here is the converter code in case anyone else needs to do something like this.

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( SyncOperationEnum ), typeof( String ) )]
public class SyncOperationConverter : IValueConverter {
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
        if( value != null && value.GetType() == typeof( SyncOperationEnum ) )
            return Enum.GetName( typeof( SyncOperationEnum ), value );

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
        if( value != null && targetType == typeof( SyncOperationEnum ) )
            foreach( object enumValue in Enum.GetValues( targetType ) )
                if( value.Equals( Enum.GetName( targetType, enumValue ) ) )
                    return enumValue;

        return null;
    }

    #endregion
```

And my XAML now looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SyncOperationConverter x:Key="SyncConverter" />

    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SyncOperationValues"
                    MethodName="GetNames"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:SyncOperationEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="SyncListTemplate">
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,20,0" x:Name="olDetails"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=OlContact}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
        <ComboBox x:Name="SyncOp" 
            Width="120" Height="19"
            Margin="4,0,10,0" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SyncOperationValues}}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Operation,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource SyncConverter}}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a situation similar to this and setting the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property on the ComboBox to "False" fixed it.  The way I understand it, setting the value to "True" means the ComboBox value will be synchronized value of the current item for the ListBox.  Basically, all the ComboBoxes are bound to that same value.  It sounds like that is what you are experiencing.  Try:

```
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
```

Comment: This is closer.  I verified that setting it to False fixes the problem; however, the reason I set it to "True" is that when the Window first comes up, all of the ComboBoxes have no selected value rather than the value of the "Operation" property they are bound to.

Comment: Try binding to SelectedValue rather than SelectedItem on the ComboBox

Comment: Just tried that, it did not fix the problem.  Still nothing selected.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your "Operation" property should be a Static property. Since it bind to every ComboBox when you change it,
So everything else is right in your XAML just make the property like bellow

```
    static SyncOperationEnum _operation;

    public static SyncOperationEnum Operation
    {
        get { return _operation; }
        set { _operation = value;}
    }
```

Comment: "Operation" is an instance property on the object the ListBox is binding to. If I change it to static I simply get a compiler error satting taht it cannot be accessed since it is not an instance property.

Comment: I should note - the ListBox is binding to an ObservableCollecton<T> of objects, each of those objects contains the Operation property.